# Why does the ratio of a chord and arc PQ in this unit circle approach 1 as PQ approaches 0?

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

I would like some help with this part in my textbook please:

[image: Figure 2.20]

It mentions that the chord and arc length of PQ → $1$ as the arc PQ → $0$; however I just can't seem to see it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"Then the ratio [...] **evidently** approaches $1$ [...]"* ... This is decidedly *not* evident. The typical approach(!) here is to invoke the so-called [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Second_example) to show that the value of $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ is (for small-enough $\theta$) trapped between values whose limiting behavior *is* evident. In particular, as the Wikipedia link explains, we find that $$\cos\theta \leq \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\leq 1$$ for small $\theta$, so that the limiting value of the ratio is trapped between $1$ and $\cos0$ (also $1$).

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the long bar which means "ratio" when you write at the bottom "the chord and arc length of PQ → 1 as the arc PQ → 0", it is "the **ratio** of the lengths of the chord over the length of the arc which tends to 1.

Comment: The nice thing about the Wikipedia proof Blue links to is that unlike many proofs often offered in beginning calculus classes, it uses area rather than arclength to prove the necessary inequalities. The inequalities follow by the general principle that if a region $A$ is inside a region $B$, then the area of $A$ is $\le$ the area of $B$. To get bounds on $\frac {\sin \theta}{\theta}$, the arclength proofs require the user to just accept that the circle arc is shorter than some polygonal path.